# Migration notice link outdated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

[This question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/810/game-theory-strategies-to-overcome-holdout-problem) on Cognitive Sciences was migrated from Economics. The link in the migration notice on CogSci links to [this completely unrelated *answer*](https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/493/revisions). *(Edit: the notice has now been removed)*

It seems the migration came from [a previous incarnation of Economics.se which was closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics). A new Economics Beta was started with the same subdomain so the URL happens to be valid—but unrelated.

I'm not sure how I would search for migrated questions from now-closed sites so I'm not sure, but I would guess that in most cases there would be a dead link and in this case it is just pure luck that the URL points to a valid post. I'm also not sure if these is an extreme edge-case or not.

Is this working as expected? And if so is it possible for migration notices to be auto-updated when sites are closed and/or URLs change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only real solution for this is to just clear the migration history off the post, as I have now done.

If the site was closed, then normally the sites would just redirect you to the Area 51 proposal indicating it was closed. But when a site gets recreated, those links all get invalidated in favor of the current site.

If you run across problems like this in the future, you can simply flag the question and ask for the migration history to be cleared so that the bad link goes away.

As an aside, you *can* find the original question in the data dump of that site, which is linked on the [original Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics).